# Youtube web scraping with pyqt5 suddenly stop working

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube, pyqt5

I am using pyqt5 to web **scraping** youtube playlist to get all videos urls.

The code was working and I try it two days before and it was working good but I try to use it today and it doesn't give me any url and returns an empty array

Here is the code

```py
import sys
import urllib.request

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl 

class Page(QWebEnginePage): 

    def __init__(self, url): 
        print("Please wait ...")
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self) 
        self.html = '' 
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished) 
        self.load(QUrl(url)) 
        self.app.exec_() 
    def _on_load_finished(self): 
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable) 
        print('Load finished') 
    def Callable(self, html_str): 
        self.html = html_str 
        self.app.quit() 

playlist = []

url = input("Enter the Youtube Playlist URL : ")

page = Page(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('a',{"class":"ytd-playlist-video-renderer"}))
```

Print gives my an empty array

So what is the problem ?

Comment: Have you checked "page.html" has class to "ytd-playlist-video-renderer"?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and it gives me a strange html code that is very different than the html code when I use inspect in chrome and no ytd-playlist-video-renderer found 
but it is there when I use inspect in chrome
I don't know what happened it was working perfectly

Comment: YouTube probably changed the access policies, you could share the url of the playlist to test

Comment: All playlist urls are not working

Comment: Is it so complicated to pass a url?

Comment: I use this links to download a playlist either all videos or specific videos from it.
is there another way to get the links ?

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ not scrapping

Comment: Thank you @barny . I wrote it with double p and check the spell checker and it didn't give me any mistakes so I left it , sorry English isn’t my first language

Comment: Scrapping is a real word, but means almost the opposite of scraping. Scrapping is throwing away like rubbish.